# Postgres: how to start a procedure right after database start?

Tags: postgresql

I have dozens of unlogged tables, and doc says that an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown.

Based on that, I need to check some tables after database starts to see if they are "empty" and do something about it.

So in short words, I need to execute a procedure, right after database is started.

How the best way to do it?

PS: I'm running Postgres 9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Comment: Maybe a small bash script, that will be launched right after a DB start? In such script you can use `psql` to call a function in the DB.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change database startup script. I need to do it  by the database it self.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature available (at time of writing, latest version was PostgreSQL 9.2). Your only options are:

- Start a script from the PostgreSQL init script that polls the database and when the DB is ready locks the tables and populates them;
- Modify the startup script to use `pg_ctl start -w` and invoke your script as soon as `pg_ctl` returns; this has the same race condition but avoids the need to poll.
- Teach your application to run a test whenever it opens a new pooled connection to detect this condition, lock the tables, and populate them; or
- Don't use unlogged tables for this task if your application can't cope with them being empty when it opens a new connection

There's been discussion of connect-time hooks on pgsql-hackers but no viable implementation has been posted and merged.

It's possible you could do something like this with PostgreSQL bgworkers, but it'd be a LOT harder than simply polling the DB from a script.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres now has `pg_isready` for determining if the database is ready.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pg-isready.html